# Can not deploy dotnet core app using pubxml file in gitlab

Tags: c#, .net-core, gitlab

I am trying to use a `.pubxml` profile in order to deploy my app in gitlab using gitlab job runner.

Here is my `yml` file

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0

stages:
    - deploy

variables:
    test: "Tests/UnitTests/FeatureSwitch.UnitTests"

before_script:
    - "dotnet restore"

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script: 
        - "cd FeatureSwitch"
        - 'dotnet build -c Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Properties/PublishProfiles/Development.pubxml'
```

This is my profile:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProjectGuid>...</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>https://...</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>...</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>False</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>...</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Also `Development.pubxml.user` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TimeStampOfAssociatedLegacyPublishXmlFile />
    <EncryptedPassword>...</EncryptedPassword>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The profile file is auto generated from VS, and it works fine if I click publish from VS.

But it does not work if i run it from gitlab.

The error looks like below:

> > Build FAILED.
> >      /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish/targets/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.MSDeploy.targets(171,5): error MSB6004: The specified task executable location "%ProgramW6432%/IIS/Microsoft Web Deploy V3/msdeploy.exe" is invalid. [/builds/rajmond.burgaj/featureswitch/FeatureSwitch/FeatureSwitch.csproj]
> >          0 Warning(s)
> >          1 Error(s)
> >      Time Elapsed 00:00:08.21
> >      ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

After searching I did only find one similar issue [here](https://4programmers.net/Forum/Inne/326531-net_core_gitlab_ci_the_specified_task_executable_location_is_invalid) which does not have any answer!

Does anybody know what might be the issue ?

Is this related to gitlab itself or something wrong with commands ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I am having absolutely the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately no, from the last time I checked this, a year ago or more there was no solution out there, but maybe now a lot of stuff have changed and gitlab supports it somehow. But i dont know how it can be done.

Comment: This is quite annoying, cause I am trying to deploy to IIS on my server, and I can just think about this way or FTP (didn't try yet, but FTP probably is going to take ages, even if works). Did you find any other workaround for your problem?

Comment: I really gave up and used FTP at the end because I was using a shared hosting provider anyway. In case your server supports docker, u can also publish docker images in gitlab and deploy from there using docker images but dont know if its worth the effort for u.

Comment: Its also a shared hosting using plesk, I don't think it accepts docker images. Thanks for the help.